# Do fiber and structure group determine the fiber bundle over a given space?

Tags: general-topology, fiber-bundles

So, let's say $B$ is a honest topological space (path connected and locally simply-connected), and we are given two fiber bundles over $B$
$$ F_i \hookrightarrow E_i \to B, \qquad i=1,2 $$
with structure groups $G_i$. Now suppose that

1. the fibers are the same: $F_1=F_2$.
2. the structure groups are the same: $G_1 = G_2$.

Can we conclude that the total spaces are also the same, i.e. that $E_1=E_2$ ?

Comment: Are the two double-covers of the circle not a counter example? I.e the trivial double cover and the connected double cover.

Comment: Do they have the same structure group?

Comment: I'm going to assume the structure group is the same as the deck transformation group for covering spaces, (I've never formally been taught fiber bundles so this might be totally incorrect) In which case they're both $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For a covering space yes, the structure group is the group of deck transformations. But this group depends on the action of the fundamental group of B on the total space. Considering the non connected, trivial double cover of $S^1$ ($E$=disjoint union of two circles) the action of the fundamental group on $E$ is trivial (go around the circle and come back to the starting point) and $G$ is the trivial group.

Considering the connected, non trivial double cover of $S^1$ ($E=S^1$) the action of the fundamental group on $E$ is non trivial (go up and go down on the spiral) and $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Let $p\colon S^1\sqcup S^1\rightarrow S^1$ be the trivial double cover and let $f\colon S^1\sqcup S^1\rightarrow S^1\sqcup S^1$ permute the circles. Clearly $f$ is a non-trivial homeomorphism and $p\circ f=p$ and so $f$ is a non-trivial deck transformation. I was under the impression that the monodromy action of $\pi_1(B)$ on the fiber $F$ was only compatible with the deck transformation group $Aut(p)$ if the total space $E$ was connected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely not.

Here's a simple example. Depending on the choice of transition functions, a bundle of the form
$$[-1,1] \hookrightarrow E \to S^1$$
and structure group $\Bbb Z/2 = \{-1,1\}$ (acting on the fiber $[-1,1]$ via multiplication) can have total space a cylinder or a Möbius band.

**Edit:** Let $[-1,1] \hookrightarrow E \to S^1$ be a fiber bundle with structure group $\Bbb Z/2 = \{-1, 1\}$ as above. I'll construct the cases where $E$ is the cylinder $S^1 \times [-1,1]$ and where $E$ is the Möbius band using transition functions.

Suppose that $E$ is trivialized over $U_1 = (-\varepsilon, \pi +\varepsilon)$ and $U_2 = (\pi-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ (here $\varepsilon$ is just a small positive number and we are thinking of $S^1$ as $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$). We have that
$$U_1 \cap U_2 = (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \cup (\pi-\varepsilon, \pi+\varepsilon).$$
Assume that on the component $(\pi-\varepsilon, \pi+\varepsilon)$ of $U_1 \cap U_2$, the transition function is given by
$$\theta_{12}(x) = 1 \text{ for all } x \in (\pi-\varepsilon, \pi+\varepsilon).$$
Since a transition function must be continuous and $\Bbb Z/2$ is disconnected, we see that the only possibilities for $\theta_{12}|_{(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)}$ are
\begin{align*}
 \text{(a)} & \quad \theta_{12}(x) = 1 \text{ for all } x \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon), \\
 \text{(b)} & \quad \theta_{12}(x) = -1 \text{ for all } x \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon).
\end{align*}
Case (a) gives the trivial bundle over $S^1$. In case (b), we have that the total space $E$ is the Möbius band.

To visualize the two cases (a) and (b) above, note that based on our choices so far, we have a strip $[-\varepsilon,2\pi+\varepsilon] \times [-1,1]$ and we need to glue the two ends $[-\varepsilon,0] \times [-1,1]$ and $[2\pi, 2\pi+\varepsilon] \times [-1,1]$ together to obtain $E$. Choice (a) just identifies the two ends trivially and gives us the cylinder $S^1 \times [-1,1]$. Choice (b) makes us rotate one of the ends before gluing, introducing a twist and hence giving us a Möbius band.

If we fix the base space $B$, fiber $F$, structure group $G$, and transition functions $\{\theta_{\beta\alpha}\}$, then the total space $E$ **is** determined. Essentially, $E$ is made up of pieces $U_\alpha \times F$ where $\{U_\alpha\}$ is an open cover of $B$, and the transition functions $\{\theta_{\beta\alpha}\}$ tell us how to glue together these pieces along overlaps where $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \neq \varnothing$. The transition functions are just a recipe for gluing together the locally trivial pieces of the bundle to obtain $E$.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it! But what happens if we also fix the transition functions? Do we have a unique bundle then?

Comment: Could you please expand this and describe the transition functions of each case? That would be really useful!

Comment: @Abramo: I've addressed both of your questions in an edit.

Comment: Your answer suggests that you think that you can get infinitely many nonisomorphic line bundles over the circle by putting in more and more twists.  I pretty sure this is not the case: what would the transition functions look like for, say, two twists?  I believe that the topological Picard group of $S^1$ is indeed $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: C.f. for instance http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22950/why-isnt-the-mobius-band-an-algebraic-line-bundle.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks for pointing this out. One should always check the details themselves before leaving them to the reader... The only possible total spaces in my example are $S^1 \times [-1,1]$ and the Möbius band.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your question for principal $G$-bundles over an honest space $M$. Note that the structure group of a principal $G$-bundle is $G$.

Isomorphism classes of principal $G$-bundles over $M$ are in one-to-one correspondence with homotopy classes of maps $M\to BG$, the classifying space of $G$. So in particular, the fiber $G$ and base $M$ characterize the bundle if and only if $[M,BG]$ is trivial.

See also this MSE question: [Classification of general fibre bundles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34888/classification-of-general-fibre-bundles)

Comment: What do you mean by BG?

Comment: A classifying space for $G$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space